# My button becomes misaligned when I wrap it in an <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I was wondering whether one of you could shed some insight on why one of my buttons becomes misaligned when I wrap it in an `<a>` tag.

I have

```
<div class="outerdiv" id="navbar">
    <a href="runningCalculator.html"><input type="button" class="navbutton" value="Running Calculator"/></a>
    <input type="button" class="navbutton"/>
    <input type="button" class="navbutton"/>
</div>
```

in my `body`, and the first button is showing with margin at the top while the other 2, as desired, aren't.

Here's the CSS for the `navbutton` class:

```
.navbutton
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 15;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(51,51,51);
}
```

Comment: Why would you wrap a button in an anchor tag?

Comment: You'll need to provide a fiddle, without a working example it could be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't wrap buttons in anchor tags. It is forbidden by the HTML specification and gives inconsistent (and often undesirable) results across browsers.

If you want the functionality of a link then use a link. If you want the functionality of a button then use a button.

Then apply CSS to make whichever element you selected look the way you want.

Comment: I thought one way to make a button act like a hyperlink was to do wrap it like I did. I actually got the idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: You mean the answer that says *This markup is no longer valid in HTML5 and will neither validate nor always work as potentially expected. Use another approach.*? @user3443528

Comment: lol. When I wanted my button to act as a hyperlink, I scrolled down the page on that StackOverflow question until I found the "fix" that would require me to write the least amount of additional code. I guess that's not how I should choose answers in the future.